# Function invoke in Flutter to get attributes from Firebase

Tags: flutter, async-await

I want to define and invoke a function in Flutter to get required values from Firebase.
In the below code I have defined getCourseDetails() function and invoking it in the container by passing a parameter to get the value.
The Course_Details collection has many documents with course_id's which has attribute with name (course_name, subtitle). I use these values to build a listview cards in next steps.

I am able to get the values from the function using async await, but for some reason the values keeps on updating and never stops. It kind of goes to loop and keeps on running. I added print statements to check and it keeps on running and printing.
Please let me know what wrong I am doing here or how to define function here to avoid the issue. Thanks

```
class _CourseProgressListState extends State<CourseProgressList> {
  String course_name, subtitle;

  getCourseDetails(course_id_pass) async {
    DocumentSnapshot document = await Firestore.instance.collection('Course_Details').document(course_id_pass).get();
    setState(() {
      course_name = document.data['course_name'];
      subtitle = document.data['subtitle'];
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection('Enrolling_Courses').where('student_id', isEqualTo: widget.id).snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.data == null) return Text('no data');
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
                var course_details = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                getCourseDetails(course_details['course_id']);
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Application Flow

On first build of `CourseProgressList` the Widget State `_CourseProgressListState` is loaded. This State in the `build` method uses a StreamBuilder to retrieve all documents from the firestore. As soon as the documents are received the StreamBuilder attempts to build the ListView using the ListViewBuilder.

In the ListViewBuilder you make the `async` call  to `getCourseDetails(course_details['course_id']);` which when complete populates two attributes `String course_name, subtitle;`

The problem starts here

#### Problem

When you call

```
        setState(() { 
            course_name = document.data['course_name'];
            subtitle = document.data['subtitle'];
        });
```

you trigger a Widget rebuild and so the process starts over again to rebuild the entire widget.

NB. refreshing state of a stateful widget will trigger a widget rebuild

NB. `Firestore.instance.collection('Enrolling_Courses').where('student_id', isEqualTo: widget.id).snapshots()` returns a stream of realtime changes implying that your List will also refresh each time there is a change to this collection

#### Recommendations

1. If you do not need to call the `setState` try not to call the setState.
2. You could let `getCourseDetails(course_id_pass)` return a `Future/Stream` with the values desired and use another `FutureBuilder/StreamBuilder` in your ListViewBuilder to return each ListViewItem. Your user may appreciate seeing some items instead of waiting for all the course details to be available
3. Abstract your request to firestore in a repository/provider or another function/class which will do the entire workload, i.e retrieving course ids then subsequently the course details and returning a `Future<List<Course>>` / `Stream<List<Course>>` for your main StreamBuilder in this widget (see reference snippet below as a guide and requires testing)

#### Reference Snippet

Your abstraction could look something like this but this decision is up to you. There are many software design patterns to consider or you could just start by getting it working.

```
        //let's say we had a class Course
        class Course {
            String courseId;
            String courseName;
            String subTitle;
    
            Course({this.courseId,this.courseName,this.subTitle})
        }
    
        Stream<List<Course>> getStudentCourses(int studentId){
          return Firestore.instance
                        .collection('Enrolling_Courses')
                        .where('student_id', isEqualTo: studentId)
                        .snapshots()
                        //extract documents from snapshot
                        .map(snapshot => snapshot?.data ?? [])
                        //we will then request details for each document
                        .map(documents => 
        /*because this is an asynchronous request for several 
        items which we are all interested in at the same time, we can wrap 
    this in 
        a Future.wait and retrieve the results of all as a list
        */
                             Future.wait(
                                documents.map(document => 
                      //making a request to firestore for each document
                                   Firestore.instance
                                            .collection('Course_Details')
                                            .document(document['course_id'])
                                            .get()
        /* making a final transformation turning 
        each document into a Course item which we can easily pass to our 
        ListBuilder/Widgets
        */
                                            .then(courseItem => Course(
                                                   
    courseId:document['course_id'],
                                                   courseName: 
        courseItem.data['course_name'],
                                                   subTitle: 
        courseItem.data['subtitle']
                                                  )
                                             )
                                )
                             )
                        );
                        
        }
```

#### References/Resources

FutureBuilder - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

StreamBuilder - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html

Future.wait - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future/wait.html